# Why is new java.util.Date(Long.MIN_VALUE) in Java equal to "Sun Dec 02 11:47:04 EST 292269055"?

Tags: java, datetime

So as in the title, in Java, if I do

```
System.out.print(new java.util.Date(Long.MAX_VALUE));
System.out.print(new java.util.Date(0));
System.out.print(new java.util.Date(-86400000));
System.out.print(new java.util.Date(Long.MIN_VALUE));
```

I get as output

```
Sun Aug 17 02:12:55 EST 292278994
Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 EST 1969
Tue Dec 30 19:00:00 EST 1969
Sun Dec 02 11:47:04 EST 292269055
```

So year values go `Long.MAX_VALUE > Long.MIN_VALUE > 0 > -86400000`? What happened? Why isn't `Date(Long.MIN_VALUE)` a negative year?

Searching, I wasn't able to find any information related to this, and the Java documentation doesn't mention anything about it.

I am using Java 8.

Also, executing the following

```
(new java.util.Date(Long.MIN_VALUE).getYear() >= new java.util.Date(0).getYear())
```

returns `true`, but

```
(new java.util.Date(Long.MIN_VALUE).after(new java.util.Date(0)))
```

returns `false`?

Comment: Changing the formatter, you would have noticed that with `Long.MIN_VALUE` argument, the date is before christ! :-)

Comment: As a courtesy, please leave comments explaining what is wrong with the question before down-voting so that it can be correct/avoided in the future. Thank you.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder By 'proper formatter' you mean like GregorianCalendar? (Which gives me the same year)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ok. Using SimpleDateFormater("y") gives me the year as a positive number, and SimpleDateFormater("Y")  gives me the year as a negative number... because reasons I guess? X3

Comment: @Tezra: Man that's ugly. I was using the wrong format specifier anyway, it should have been `y`, which (as you say) prints a positive number. Well, at least that's consistent with GregorianCalendar. :-) I don't think `GregorianCalendar` or `Date` documents a range limit (in fact, `GregorianCalendar` says it can apply the rules infinitely forward or backward, but that doing so into the past is historically inaccurate), but I think you're blowing a range limitation somewhere.

Comment: I still find it funny that seems to `Long.MAX_VALUE` correspond to 292277024 years after the epoch, but `Long.MIN_VALUE` to 292267086 years before the epoch.

Comment: Those of us who are happy to have transitioned to using [the newer `java.time` classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-frame.html) may use this opportunity for noting that they come with well documented upper and lower bounds (year is +/– 999 999 999).

Comment: For `getYear()`, it’s deprecated, so you should not ne concerned about what it returns. :-) However, it returns an `int`, and the years you get overflow the `int` range, so which year is greater is somewhat random.

Comment: @OleV.V. It's not overflow, negative years just print as positive numbers, and toString() is not deprecated but it uses getYear so I am concerned. Also, for min-max years, you have to count leap years, and leap seconds, and there is no year 0 and skipped leap years, and however many other exceptions there are to the 'normal' flow of time X3

Comment: I’m taking back the part about overflow. 292278994 fits nicely in an `int`. It seems that `getYear()` subtracts 1900 from the year-of-era and returns the result. So `new java.util.Date(0).getYear()` gives 70 (possibly 69 in some time zones). The same happens BC: a date in year 2000 BC, `getYear()` will return 100. For `Long.MIN_VALUE` I would expect 292267155, which is clearly more than 70.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so digging through [`Date` source](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/Date-source.html), `getYear()` is

```
/**
* Returns the difference between the year represented by this
* <code>Date</code> object and 1900.
*
* @return the year minus 1900 represented by this date object.
* @deprecated Use Calendar instead of Date, and use get(Calendar.YEAR)
* instead.  Note the 1900 difference in the year.
* @see Calendar
* @see #setYear(int)
*/
public int getYear() {
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  cal.setTimeInMillis(time);
  return cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1900;
}
```

So, `Date.getYear()` is actually `Calendar.getYear() - 1900`. (Why `-1900`?)

> Subtract 1900 why? Between 1960 and 1995 years were usually written
>   with just two digits, e.g., 60 or 95. When Java came out, the ”year
>   2000 problem“ arising from this fact was being talked about, so they
>   didn’t want to return just year % 100, the last two digits. So they
>   figured subtracting 1900 would still allow you to figure out the
>   century, and everyone should be happy. Well, we aren`t really. :-) –
>   Ole V.V.

`Calendar.getInstance()` ([source](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/Calendar-source.html)) defaults to `java.util.GregorianCalendar` ([source](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/GregorianCalendar-source.html)).

So, in the `Calendar` abstract…

```
public void setTimeInMillis(long time) {
  clear();
  this.time = time;
  isTimeSet = true;
  computeFields();
}
```

And `computeFields()` is long and complicated, but tracing it long enough. you find

```
if (year <= 0) {
  fields[ERA] = BC;
  fields[YEAR] = 1 - year;
} else {
  fields[ERA] = AD;
  fields[YEAR] = year;
}
```

SO! Long story short, `Date` uses the `GregorianCalendar`, which displays negative years as a positive number, but `Date` doesn't have a way to check the `Calendar` era… So don't use `Date` for dates before the year 1 AD. And this is where encapsulation fails; you expect 1 behaviour, but inherit another that you are never told about! (I feel stupid now, but at least I wasn't the only one confused about this behaviour.)

Comment: Subtract 1900 why? Between 1960 and 1995 years were usually written with just two digits, e.g., 60 or 95. When Java came out, the ”year 2000 problem“ arising from this fact was being talked about, so they didn’t want to return just `year % 100`, the last two digits. So they figured subtracting 1900 would still allow you to figure out the century, and everyone should be happy. Well, we aren`t really. :-)

Answer (score 4):

First things first: The following

```
 Long.MIN_VALUE > -86400000
```

evaluates to `false`.

On the other hand, negative values for the constructor in the Date class mean dates in the calendar before "the epoch", namely **January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT**.

So a date constructed with `Long.MIN_VALUE` is a way back in the past. Changing the way you print the `Date` may help you to spot the issue…

```
    System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy GG HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(new Date(Long.MAX_VALUE / 1000)));
    System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy GG HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(new Date(0)));
    System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy GG HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(new Date(-86400000)));
    System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy GG HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(new Date(Long.MIN_VALUE)));
    System.out.println(Long.MIN_VALUE > -86400000);
```

So, `new Date(Long.MIN_VALUE)` is a date before Christ.

The formatter patterns are very helpful to identify such spots.

In this case **G** means ***era designator***, and all the pattern designators are [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: `yyyy` still shows the date for `Long.MIN_VALUE` in the future. I think the OP is just blowing a range limitation that isn't documented.

Comment: You explanation would benefit greatly from (1) reminding us what the `GG` letters are in a date format sonce these are not used often (2) including the output of your code so we don’t have to run it ourselves to see the point.

Comment: Hi @OleV.V., i will update the aswern, thansk for the sugestion

Answer (score 2):

The other Answers are correct. A few more notes here.

## java.time

> Why is new java.util.Date(Long.MIN_VALUE) in Java

New? Not new at all. The [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) class is very old, bundled with the original release of Java.

That troublesome old class is now legacy, supplanted by the *java.time* classes. Specifically, the [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class. To convert to/from, see new methods added to the old class.

As for the maximum/epoch/minimum values, those are defined as constants.

- [`Instant.MAX`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#MAX)
  1000000000-12-31T23:59:59.999999999Z
- [`Instant.EPOCH`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#EPOCH)
  1970-01-01T00:00:00Z
- [`Instant.MIN`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#MIN)
  -1000000000-01-01T00:00Z

### Beware of using the limits

Beware of making any practical use of the minimum or maximum value.

If your intent is for something like meaning "unknown value", use another value. Many other tools such as databases will have very different limits, so you may run into problems. Also, such extreme values may not have any recognizable meaning to future readers/programmers/admins. Such values may even be mistaken for an error or bug.

If working with only recent dates, I would use the `Instant.EPOCH` for such a flag. The start of 1970 is recognizable by many technical folks as being special.

## ISO 8601

The strings seen above are all in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

The java.time classes use these standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings.

To generate strings in other formats, see the `DateTimeFormatter` class.

## Java 8 and later

> I am using Java 8.

Then you should definitely be migrating from the old classes to modern *java.time* classes. They are an *enormous* improvement.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

With a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) complying with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later, you may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. No need for strings or java.sql.* classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Very useful information. Just to clarify, I meant 'new' as in the java keyword. Also, the original intent of using a date.min was actually for a start field meant to indicate "since the dawn of time". I have since settled on "Since 1AD" so that I don't have to worry about what era, and that should function the same the dawn of time for my system.

Answer (score 1):

I found a possible implementation of [`java.util.Date`](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/computing/pag/tmp/html_dir/java/util/Date.java.html) where the final two lines of `toString()` are

```
1029    sb.append(' ').append(date.getYear());  // yyyy
1030    return sb.toString();
```

So `toString` relies on `getYear`, which in turn gives the observed behaviour, e.g.

```
Date d = new Date(Long.MIN_VALUE);
System.out.println(d.getYear());
```

will indeed print

> 292267155

Comment: OK, but can you explain why there is any output at all, rather than an exception or something?

Comment: I'm using Java 8 which says "Allocates a Date object and initializes it to represent the specified number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT." The old message would explain why Long.Min is wrong, but not why the output is a date between 0 and max.

Comment: @RobinTopper For the > chain, I'm going off the printed year... but it seems internally there is a discrepancy in printed date and date value?

Comment: @OlafDietsche Why is a negative value not allowed? That would mean that Date must not be used for any dates before 1 January 1970.